# Changing image alpha

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, transparency

In my application I am trying to change the alpha of a icon (image view) in my input field when
it's selected, filled or leaved blank.

I've written this code but nothing is happening, I am sure I wrote the image names as they are named in my image directory.

Sample code;

```
- (IBAction)passwordInputTab:(id)sender {

    UIImageView *imageLockIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lock-icon.png"]];
    imageLockIcon.alpha = 1;
    //self.txtPassword.alpha = 1;

    if ([[self.txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        //self.txtUsername.alpha = 0.5;
        UIImageView *imageUserIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-icon.png"]];
        imageUserIcon.alpha = 0.5;
    }
}

- (IBAction)usernameInputTab:(id)sender {

    UIImageView *imageUserIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-icon.png"]];
    imageUserIcon.alpha = 1;

    NSLog(@"==> %@", imageUserIcon);

    //userIcon.alpha = 0.1;

    if ([[self.txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""]) {

        UIImageView *imageLockIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lock-icon.png"]];
        imageLockIcon.alpha = 0.5;
        NSLog(@"==> %@", imageLockIcon);
        //self.txtPassword.alpha = 0.5;
    }
}
```

Log;

```
2014-09-18 21:47:10.882 ...[1280:60b] ==> <UIImageView: 0x14e8dd90; frame = (0 0; 17 16); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x14e8de10>>
2014-09-18 21:47:10.884 ...[1280:60b] ==> <UIImageView: 0x14d66770; frame = (0 0; 12 16); alpha = 0.5; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x14da43d0>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new UIImageViews, if you created them in the InterfaceBuilder you need to create a `@property` for each one of them and link the IBOutlets on your storyboard/xib.

If you want to create the UIImageViews programmatically you are only forgetting to add:

```
[self.view addSubview:YOUR_IMAGEVIEW];
```

Example:

```
[self.view addSubview:imageUserIcon];
```

Comment: Thanks Marck! Solved by the IBOUtlet! :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're creating a UIImageView but it is not being added to the view hierarchy. If you are trying to change the alpha on an existing UIImageView you'll need to provide a reference to it via an IBOutlet to adjust its properties.